# Can we reuse an exported function in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, commonjs

I have this in my `.js` file:

```
exports.generate = function(details) {
    // bunch of code
    // returns Promise
}

exports.save = function(details){
    exports.generate(details)
     .then(function(id){
      //save in db
      })
}
```

Is it okay to use an exported function like this? Or is there a better way..?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on if you want consumers of the module to be able to influence the module's behavior by overwriting `exports.generate` (e.g. `require('foo').generate = function() {...}`).

If you don't want users to be able to influence it in this way, then your best bet is going to be pulling out the `generate()` function and naming it, then exporting that and using the function directly by name inside `save()`:

```
function generate(details) {
  // ...
}

exports.generate = generate;
exports.save = function(details) {
  generate(details).then(function(id) {
    // ...
  });
};
```

Otherwise if you *do* want to allow users to override the `generate()` functionality, then what you are currently doing is fine.

Comment: I want consumers to be able to use the `generate` method

Comment: So, I guess I'll go with `function generate(){}` way.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _this=this;
exports.save = function(details) {
  _this.generate(details) ...
};
```